# Set width SnackBar

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm setting up a SnackBar and would like to set its maximum width, which would be limited by the width of the field for filling in information (I marked the borders in red in the picture).

The field itself for filling in information I limit using BoxConstraints (maxWidth: 800).

How can I limit the maximum width of the SnackBar ?

```
class _FormForDeviceUpdate extends State {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: Container(
                constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 800),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Form(
                    key: _formKey,
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new Text(
                          'Desire operation system version',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                        ),
                        
                        ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                              _formKey.currentState?.reset();
                              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                                  .showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                                content: const Text(
                                  'Your request has been sent to the administrator',
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                ),
                                backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
                                duration: const Duration(seconds: 4),
                                action: SnackBarAction(
                                  label: 'Dismiss',
                                  textColor: Colors.black,
                                  onPressed: () {},
                                ),
                                behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
                                shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
                              ));
                            }
                          },
                          child: const Text(
                            'Submit',
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                          ),
                          style: ButtonStyle(
                              backgroundColor:
                                  MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.yellow)),
                        )
                      ],
                    )))));
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your `From` with `LayoutBuilder` to get it's parent's `constraints` and assign `constraints.maxwidth` to `Snackbar` `width` property like so:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.grey,
          constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 800),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: LayoutBuilder(
            builder: (context, constraints) {
              return Form(
                key: _formKey,
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Text(
                      'Desire operation system version',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                          _formKey.currentState?.reset();
                          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                            width: constraints.maxWidth,
                            content: const Text(
                              'Your request has been sent to the administrator',
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                            ),
                            backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
                            duration: const Duration(seconds: 4),
                            action: SnackBarAction(
                              label: 'Dismiss',
                              textColor: Colors.black,
                              onPressed: () {},
                            ),
                            behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
                            shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
                          ));
                        }
                      },
                      child: const Text(
                        'Submit',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                      style: ButtonStyle(
                          backgroundColor:
                              MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.yellow)),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Take in mind that `constraints` will also take `padding` into calculation, so if your `Container` has `width: 800` and `padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0)`, constraints will give you `maxwidth` of `780` when it subtracts both `left` and `right` `padding` from parent's maximum `width`.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code hope its help to you, just set [**`width`**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SnackBar/width.html) of [**`SnackBar`**](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/snackbars)

Your Snackbar method:

```
   lastLeadSubmitSnackBar() {
    final snackBar =SnackBar(
      width: 150,
      content: Text('Snackbar Width'),
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      elevation: 6.0,
      duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
      behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
          Radius.circular(20),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Your Widget:

```
 ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () => lastLeadSubmitSnackBar(),
        child: Text(
          'Snack',
        ),
      ),
```

Your Result-> [image]

Answer (score 0):

instead of using SnackBar on web or windows use bot_toast

this is the link ,please go through this link

https://pub.dev/packages/bot_toast

it soo much better than SnackBar